# Can't install Windows 7 on Mac Pro 3,1

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot, refit, refind

I cant install Windows 7 on my MP3,1.
I burned original iso with Windows 7 on USB using Rufus (GPT partition).
Booted with holding Option key, chosen EFI and got freeze.
I tried to run Win7 installer in rEFIt and got message "Starting bootx64.efi" and got freeze again. The same is with rEFInd.

I think the problem is in Bootloader.

I don't want to install it with BootCamp, because I don't need MacOS installed.

Earlier I have installed Debian without any problems.

What's wrong?

Comment: Life will be easier if you use Boot Camp. You've room for 6 drives in there, just set up macOS on one, Boot Camp Win onto another & set Win as the default boot. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Apple still has the info and software available but it is not an obvious find. Look here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016

You will ned to download Version 4 of Apple's BootCamp software and use that to install Windows 7 on your MacPro 3,1.

The rest of that page gives you all the info you need to do so.

**BE AWARE** that Microsoft has set end of life for Windows 7 for January of 2020 (the 15th, I think...) which means that Windows 7 will no longer get any updates after that day. It will still work but no updates. So going online should either be done with extreme caution or not at all.

Answer (score -1):

I am fairly sure you cannot install Windows directly onto a MAC. Apple rules and restrictions.

You need:  (a) Boot Camp  (b) Virtual Machine or (c) Windows box.

Comment: But I could install Debian wtihout any problems. 
I think the problem is in Bootloader.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing preventing a MacBook owner from installing Windows on it.  This answer is unfortunately not actually accurate.